# Is a microswitch ON when slightly pressed?

Tags: switches

I'm working on an old Instax camera, it has a mechanism to release photos with a series of gears. When the shutter release is pressed, the gears turn and an arm pushes the exposed photograph out of the camera. When the arm returns back to its neutral position, the camera should stop the gears from turning.

This works via a microswitch pressing against one of the cogs - the cog has a gap in and when the arm returns to its neutral position, the micro switch should fall into the gap of the cog it's next to and stop the cycle/process.

The microswitch is touching the cog and does press it in slightly like it should when the switch is not in the gap of the cog, however the force of it being pressed in isn't enough. I've tested the microswitch, it's working but it's only activating when pressed in further, so it's almost like it isn't close enough to the cog. The result of this is that the system never thinks the arm has returned to the neutral position and keeps pushing photos out of the camera.

[image: In this position, the microswitch should be ON (but isn't). You can see the gap in the cog here while the switch isn't sitting inside it]
In this position, the microswitch should be ON (but isn't). You can see the gap in the cog here while the switch isn't sitting inside it

[image: In this position, the microswitch should be OFF]
In this position, the microswitch should be OFF (it's sitting inside the gap shown in the first picture)

So my questions are - is a microswitch in the ON state when pressed in only slightly, and can a microswitch lose sensitivity over time?

A bit of background: The microswitch was working correctly before I took it apart to clean rollers inside of the camera. I was careful doing this, but after putting it back together, this process doesn't work correctly anymore sadly. I don't feel like there are any parts missing, so I'm very confused as to why the microswitch isn't working now. In an attempt to get it working, I've tried adjusting the copper microswitch part but this hasn't worked. Please excuse any bad use of technical terms if I've described anything incorrectly!

Comment: My guess is that the microswitch itself is still functioning exactly as it has been for years. What has most likely changed is the angle of the metal leaf that presses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. A snap-action microswitch. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_snap-action_switch). The snap spring is shown at (1).*

Most microswitches use a toggle or snap action. The actuator has to go beyond a certain point at which the contact arm "snaps" over to the alternate position. Similarly, on the way back a similar snap takes place. The hysteresis - the difference between switch on and switch off points - prevents the switch from chattering when on the transition.

> So my questions are - is a microswitch in the ON state when pressed in only slightly?

It could be either way. Figure 1 shows a changeover type so by using the common (left) and centre we get a normally open switch.

> ... and can a microswitch lose sensitivity over time?

Yes. Parts wear out but it was working before disassembly and doesn't now so ...

> I've tried adjusting the copper microswitch part but this hasn't worked.

Again, looking at Figure 1 you need to be careful where you bend the actuator. In the snap switch pictured you would need to bend the arm somewhere in the region above (1). If you bend it between the pivot and the black button you could lose operation completely.

Comment: Thanks of the answer. I was able to take the microswitch out of the casing (it was more difficult putting it back in) and it didn't click ON at any point, however I was able to use a meter to gauge at which point it activated. With the switch removed from the casing, I adjusted the actuator so it was pointing away from the switch. This was enough to ensure it was always ON, and only OFF when sitting in the hole of the cog.

Comment: Well done. I mustn't be a snap action type then.

Answer (score 1):

A microswitch is on when you hear it clicking. The button on the casing works sideways on a loaded spring.

Here's an open microswitch, so you can see the workings better:

[image: Open microswitch]

Can you imagine how it works? Press on the spring from above. Eventually the small plate left of the spring flips over and closes the contact from the upper assembly to the terminal pointed by the arrow.